# Integrating coupled variables by separation

Tags: integration

I'm trying to figure out how to integrate the following:

$\frac{d\dot y}{dx}+B\dot y=-\frac{g}{V_0}e^{Bx}$

This equation comes from a derivation for 2D quadratic drag found [here](https://www.arl.army.mil/arlreports/2011/ARL-TR-5612.pdf) (pg. 5), and I'm failing to see how the author is able to separate the variables in Eq. 25 to perform an integration and obtain Eq. 26. Namely:

$\frac{d\dot y}{dx}+B\dot y=-\frac{g}{V_0}e^{Bx}$

becomes

$\dot y = -\frac{g}{BV_0}\sinh (Bx)$

However, I can't seem to group the $e^{Bx}$ with $dx$ and $\dot y$ with $dy$ in a way that keeps the x's and y's separate. Either $d\dot y$ and $d\dot x$ are coupled, or $e^{Bx}$ and $\dot y$ are coupled.

As a sanity check on the author, I was able to differentiate Eq. 26 to get Eq. 25, but I don't see how to go about it the other way.

Here's my differentiation of Eq. 26 to get Eq. 25:

$\dot y = -\frac{g}{BV_0}\sinh (Bx)=-\frac{g}{2BV_0}(e^{Bx}-e^{-Bx})$

$\frac{d\dot y}{dx}=-\frac{g}{2V_0}(e^{Bx}+e^{-Bx})$

Which should also equal

$\frac{d\dot y}{dx}=-B\dot y-\frac{g}{V_0}e^{Bx}$

Substituting $\dot y$ in gives

$=-B(-\frac{g}{2BV_0}(e^{Bx}-e^{-Bx}))-\frac{g}{V_0}e^{Bx}$

$=\frac{g}{2V_0}(e^{Bx}-e^{-Bx})-\frac{2g}{2V_0}e^{Bx}$

Which indeed equals

$-\frac{g}{2V_0}(e^{Bx}+e^{-Bx})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you might want to try an integrating factor, that is turn the left hand side into a product rule. There's some more info for instance on [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) for instance, it's a general method for solving first order linear inhomogenous odes.

Multiply the whole equation by $e^{Bx}$, then it looks like

$$\frac{d }{dx}\left(\dot{y}e^{Bx}\right)=\frac{-g}{V_0}e^{2Bx}$$

Then integrate to get

$$\dot{y}e^{Bx}=\frac{-g}{2BV_0}e^{2Bx}+C$$

or

$$\dot{y}=\frac{-g}{2BV_0}e^{Bx}+Ce^{-Bx}$$

Then you need some initial conditions for x=0 say, and it could turn into a $\sinh$. It seems to say that " $\dot{y} = 0$ at $t = 0$ (which also coincides with $x = 0$)." So that $C$ the integration constant must be $C=\frac{g}{2BV_0}$

so then

$\dot{y}=\frac{-g}{BV_0}\sinh(Bx)$